# Why did heap memory come into existence?

Tags: c++, c, memory

My question is pretty much basic and as the title says I want to know why heap memory came into picture . I am aware that heap memory supports dynamic memory allocation but why same could not be done through/within stack memory when both types of memory (static and heap) exist on RAM. Why it was needed to have separate segment of memory in process address space .While posting this question I came across several posts related to heap memory topic but so far I have checked does not answer my question rather is more about definition and behaviour of heap memory.
To be more clear on my question , Why there couldn't be one large stack memory which also handles dynamic memory allocation .As we know that dynamic memory is something which is created on the fly and can be freed up when required.Also there could be memory overrun or leak issue with dynamic memory allocation but can't it be done if there was one big stack memory as be it heap or stack if memory doesnt get freed up 'then it will definitely result in wastage even in case of program exit .Having said that when both memory resides on RAM then why there was requirement of different memory structure for handling memory.

Comment: Are you asking why dynamic memory allocation was done using a heap structure? or are you asking why there was dynamic allocation at all?

Comment: I think he is refering to the second question, the why of dynamic allocation

Comment: No, I think he is referring to the first. Isn't the stack space fixed in size? Dynamic memory wouldn't work very well if your structure was a fixed size. And if you made the stack very big to accommodate dynamic allocation, there'd be a lot of wasted space.

Comment: Memory addresses in the lower space (where the stack is located) are limited. Memory addresses in the higher ranges (where the heap is located) didn't exist on early processors, and when they were created were able to be much larger. Do research on processor and memory development starting in the 1980s. (And in regards to which question is being asked, if it isn't clear you should vote to close the question until it is made so, instead of debating it in comments. There is a close reason for **unclear questions**.)

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva one major codebase I work with does not use dynamic allocation. It's used in critical applications where an out-of-memory error would be unacceptable.

Comment: Void modern OS's don't allocate a page of physical memory until that page is actually read or written to, so you can e.g. create a 1 GB stack and if you only ever push 10kB of data onto the stack, then your actual RAM usage for the stack will only be 10kB.  (The creation of the stack allocates address space but not actual physical RAM unless/until the space is actually being used)

Comment: As far as I am aware there has always been the need for both. The stack is there to keep track of where you are in the function call hierarchy. When a function returns all stack memory associate with it, including local variables is lost. If you want any value to persist independent of the  function call stack you need to store it some place else.

Comment: @Galik some systems don't store local variables in a stack (I have used one, it was very painful).  Also, it used to be more common to see systems that have separate stacks for local variables as for function calls. There are some nice advantages to this (e.g. no buffer overflow execution exploits). Just providing some historical info :)

Comment: @theartist33 The point about a stack is that it is strictly *last in, first out*. Dynamic memory can't work like that. The need for two structures is quite fundamental.It harkens back to when people wrote in assembly language, in order to perform a subroutine you needed somewhere for the CPU to dump its working registers and to pick them up again after the call had returned. But the main data the program is working on needs to be stored elsewhere so it doesn't get chewed up in the call/return stack-dumping process.

Comment: apart from the dynamic allocation issue, if a lot of stack are allocated to a program, others can't use it, as stack space must be contiguous

Comment: this is an interesting question, too bad it's so unreadable…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With stack allocation there is a strict LIFO (last-in, first-out) policy for the lifetimes of allocated objects.  That is, if you allocate object A, then object B, then object C, they will always be freed in the opposite order.

That's useful in a lot of cases, but there are also cases where you e.g. want object C to continue to exist after B and A have been destroyed.  There's no way to do that with a stack, so to handle those cases the heap was introduced.  It's harder to use correctly than stack allocation, but also more flexible/powerful.

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking time in replying and giving related information . I almost got my answer through different post for this question .Many of the answers says the same thing but I am sticking to above answer. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 2):

Usually the stack and the heap exist in a large section of memory in RAM, where the heap starts at the beginning and grows forward and the stack starts at the top of the RAM and grows backward.  Free memory in the middle can either be allocated to the stack or the heap depending on which is needed at runtime.
The main difference between the stack and the heap is how allocation is performed.  The stack requires a last-in-first-out model of memory management, whereas the heap uses dynamic memory allocation, which is more flexible but more expensive.

Many useful programming patterns cannot be represented with the less expensive memory model of the stack.  As a primary example, the memory for a growable array (a vector in C++) cannot be stored in the stack, since the amount of memory needed is unknown at compile time and may increase in the future, requiring a re-allocation.

Comment: You aren't really answering the question though.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question then.  From how I read the question, he seems familiar with the concept of dynamic memory allocation on the heap but wanted to know why the stack and the heap took up two different sections of memory.  My answer is that they share a common section of memory.

Comment: I think the answer does address exactly what the question asks.

Answer (score 2):

Memory management, including heap like allocation and freeing of memory dates back to the 1950's. The "why" for this is because there was a need for it.

Note that the IBM 360 and later family of mainframes didn't have a stack. A caller provided save area for the registers was used instead, and simple programs just used a static array for that save area. More advanced programs could dynamically allocate memory as needed (depending on the OS), so in this case, heap memory existed without a stack.

In case you're wondering, interrupts were handle via a vector of pairs of words, one used to store the current state of the machine, the other initialized sometime beforehand with the state to handle that particular interrupt.

Other older mainframes and minicomputers didn't have a stack. In some cases, similar to the IBM 360 interrupt handler, the first word of a function was used to store the return address, and actual code started with the second word and returning was done using an indirect jump via the first word (such as CDC 3150, HP 2100).

Answer (score 0):

The very simple answer to your question is that each memory type (stack and heap) must be managed by different mechanisms.  The stack memory is basically managed by the compiler and is generally managed by code generated by the compiler based on your stack requirements in the code.  Stack allocations are pushed and popped on a memory space set aside for that purpose.  Heap memory comes and goes and the amount of memory allocated can change for each pass over the same set of code, thus the space requirements are not known at compile time.

From the computer systems stand point memory is memory.  I have seen embedded systems where the embedded operating system allocates a large contiguous area of memory from the heap and points the stack pointer at that area.  So effectively the stack memory is really in the heap space and is a single allocation of heap memory managed by the heap manager.  Note that piece of memory is never going to be de-allocated during the running of the system.

So the short answer is that stack and heap memory have different requirements such that each "type" of memory has to be managed in a different way to satisfy those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how the stack actually works?

When a function is called, memory for its local variables is allocated on the stack. When the function returns, the stack winds back, with the stack pointer going back to where it was before the function was called. Everything allocated on the stack by that function will be overwritten when the next function is called.

Without the heap, you wouldn't be able to have an object or array outlive the function call that creates it.

Also, part of the advantage of the stack is locality of memory. All of your local variables are very close to each other in memory, and as such are going to be on the same memory page. Dumping tons of large object allocations onto the stack would kill that locality.

Comment: But you can return objects from functions (and the compiler can elide copies.) So effectively you can make objects outlive the function they are created in.

Comment: Nope- you'll only return shallow copies of objects. Any memory allocated to pointers held by the object will be overwritten, since it's on the stack as well.

Comment: @juanchopanza A function that returns an object can only do so because the object is allocated on the heap.

Comment: He's talking about returning the function by value, which you can in C++- technically- but it'll have the above mentioned problem.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings You can also return by value in C, of course. And your point about only returning shallow objects is unrelated. You don't have to dynamically allocate stuff in order to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Stack memory is faster than heap memory, but at the cost of flexibility.

It's like creating files on a disk. You can create a lot of files occupying a lot of space. Later you can delete some of them. Part of the space is free again and can be used by another process. This mechanism is very useful, though sometimes you run into fragmentation problem. You can think of heap allocation as a similar thing. In contrast stack memory is usually much smaller, with very simple management (just moving a stack pointer), and cannot be manipulated like heap.

You can say stack and heap are required by CPU and OS design.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between the heap and the stack is a bit arbitrary.  Conceptually, stack memory just uses memory to represent the state of functions in the function call stack.  Heap memory has a scope outside of functions in the function call stack.  In theory, both of these could occupy the same section of memory in a program though.  However, in practice they don't since the hardware and operating system are specialized for the two different uses.

Theoretically, a heap isn't necessary.  Once the scope for objects isn't the function call frame, it becomes difficult to manage object lifetimes and memory though.  Ownership of the object has to be passed higher in the call stack as functions exit, which generally means copying.  So, it would imply a serious performance penalty.

One of the other issues is that objects ultimately need to be reclaimed.  Since objects are laid out contiguously in stack memory, there would be gaps of various sizes in memory between dead objects and live objects.  Essentially this would mean the dead memory isn't usable and leaked.

So, the primary reason for a *heap* is to effectively maintain memory that's outside the scope of a function call.