# What are the reasons to allocate a pointer on the heap?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

Probably this question was already asked but I couldn't find it. Please redirect me if you you saw something.
**Question :**
what is the benefit of using :

```
myClass* pointer;
```

over

```
myClass* pointer = new(myClass);
```

From reading on other topics, I understand that the first option allocates a space on the stack and makes the pointer point to it while the second allocates a space on the heap and make a pointer point to it.
But I read also that the second option is tedious because you have to deallocate the space with delete.
So why would one ever use the second option.
I am kind of a noob so please explain in details.

**edit**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Dog
{
        public:
                void bark()
                {
                        cout << "wouf!!!" << endl;
                }

};


int main()
{

        Dog* myDog = new(Dog);
        myDog->bark();
        delete myDog;
        return 0;

}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Dog
{
        public:
                void bark()
                {
                        cout << "wouf!!!" << endl;
                }

};


int main()
{

        Dog* myDog;
        myDog->bark();
        return 0;

}
```

both compile and give me "wouf!!!". So why should I use the "new" keyword?

Comment: The first option doesn't allocate anything except for the pointer itself. Where that storage is located depends on usage. I think you may have an extra `*` in your first example.

Comment: Stack and Heap are implementation details that the language doesn't care about. What you're asking about is automatic vs dynamic storage duration.

Comment: Can i point you at the book list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: The stack is limited, sometimes a few kB, sometimes 2-8MB, so if you have large images, or dynamically growing lists, you may need to use the heap. The stack also disappears when you return from a function, which is a problem for things you want to keep.

Comment: Also [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514923/why-did-heap-memory-come-into-existence).

Comment: The first option you listed is incorrect. The second option violates current design principles. This question would have made sense several years ago, if you had gotten it right. The answer depends on scope and ownership, but you didn't give enough info on either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that the first option allocates a space on the stack and
> makes the pointer point to it while the second allocates a space on
> the heap and make a pointer point to it.

The above is incorrect -- the first option allocates space **for the pointer itself** on the stack, but doesn't allocate space for any object for the pointer to point to.  That is, the pointer isn't pointing to anything in particular, and thus isn't useful to use (unless/until you set the pointer to point to something)

In particular, it's only pure blind luck that this code appears to "work" at all:

```
Dog* myDog;
myDog->bark();   // ERROR, calls a method on an invalid pointer!
```

... the above code is invoking *undefined behavior*, and in an ideal world it would simply crash, since you are calling a method on an invalid pointer.  But C++ compilers typically prefer maximizing efficiency over handling programmer errors gracefully, so they typically don't put in a check for invalid-pointers, and since your `bark()` method doesn't actually use any data from the `Dog` object, it is able to execute without any obvious crashing.  Try making your `bark()` method virtual, OTOH, and you will probably see a crash from the above code.

> the second allocates a space on the heap and make a pointer point to
> it.

That is correct.

> But I read also that the second option is tedious because you have to
> deallocate the space with delete.

Not only tedious, but error-prone -- it's very easy (in a non-trivial program) to end up with a code path where you forgot to call delete, and then you have a memory leak.  Or, alternatively, you could end up calling delete twice on the same pointer, and then you have undefined behavior and likely crashing or data corruption.  Neither mistake is much fun to debug.

> So why would one ever use the second option.

Traditionally you'd use dynamic allocation when you need the object to remain valid for longer than the scope of the calling code -- for example, if you needed the object to stick around even after the function you created the object in has returned.  Contrast that with a stack allocation:

```
myClass someStackObject;
```

... in which `someStackObject` is guaranteed to be destroyed when the calling function returns, which is usually a good thing -- but not if you need `someStackObject` to remain in existence even after your function has returned.

These days, most people would avoid using raw/C-style pointers entirely, since they are so dangerously error-prone.  The modern C++ way to allocate an object on the heap would look like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<myClass> pointer = std::make_shared<myClass>();
```

... and this is preferred because it gives you a heap-allocated myClass object whose pointed-to-object will continue to live for as long as there is at least one std::shared_ptr pointing to it (good), but also will automagically be deleted the moment there are no std::shared_ptr's pointing to it (even better, since that means no memory leak and no need to explicitly call `delete`, which means no potential double-deletes)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice answer.
"but doesn't allocate space for any object for the pointer to point to"

Oh, I see, I was probably confused : Does
`int* ptr;`
also just alocate space for the pointer itself or also for the int it is going to point to? (Maybe for this I got confused).

"Traditionally you'd use the second object when you need the object to remain valid for longer than the scope of the calling code"

I just tried to do this :

`void foo()
{
        Dog* myDog = new(Dog);
}
int main()
{
        foo();
        myDog.bark();
        return 0;
}`

Comment: Oh, I just notice there is no newline. I'm not sure this is the right way to answer an answer...

Comment: For any type, any time you just declare a pointer (e.g. X* x;) you are only allocating space for the pointer itself.  Allocating space for an actual object of type X must be done separately (e.g. X* x = new X(); ... or equivalent, X * x; x = new X();)

Comment: In your longer-scope example in your comment, you might do it more like this:  `Dog * foo() { Dog* myDog = new Dog; return myDog; } int main() { Dog * d = foo(); d->bark(); delete d; }

Comment: Okay, makes sense

Comment: So when you return the pointer, you can still point to the object it points to because this one exists on the heap, whereas for the code bellow :
`Dog* foo() {Dog myDog(3); Dog* ptr = &myDog; return ptr;} int main() { Dog* d = foo(); d->bark(); cout << d->age << endl; return 0;} `  (I just added a attribute for the age) the pointer is return but dereferencing it gives undefined behaviour since  the object it points was destroyed because was on the stack. Is this it? I am now going to inform myself about unique_ptr and shared_ptr :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Returning a pointer to a stack object is always a mistake, for that reason :)